# Grab the types of an Object of Generic Types

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an object of Observables, which I would like to map to an object of the emitted values.

Is it possible to grab the type (xxx) of the Observables to type the Output object?

```
type InputType = { [key: string]: Observable<xxx>  };
type OutputType<T extends InputType> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P][xxx] };

function map(input: InputType): Observable<OutputType> {
   const keys = Object.keys(input);
   const values$ = Object.values(input);

   return combineLatest(values$, (...args) => {
      const output = {} as OutputType;
      keys.forEach((key, index) => output[key] = args[index]);
      return output;
   });
}
```

example:

```
const mapFn: (input: {a: Observable<number>, b: Observable<string>}) => Observable<{a: number, b: string}>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get out what is inside the generic type we need to use `infer`. Consider:

```
type InputType<V> = { [key: string]: Observable<V> };
type OutputType<T extends InputType<any>> = Observable<{ [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends 
Observable<infer Inside> ? Inside : never }>;

declare function map<Input extends InputType<any>>(input: Input): OutputType<Input>;
```

Most important part is:

- `[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Observable<infer Inside> ? Inside : never }` - we say our output type will be object type with the same keys as original but values will be types inside Observable.

Full code but with mocked version of Observable type is in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEFsHsGMGsGdSQGZIEbwKYCcBuBDNAG0wCgAXATwAdNQB5DHA4zAHgA0A%20UAXlADepUCNABLAHbwxAE0wAuUB1IBfUnOhF82OsgCuE6OTGQJ6LHkIlOXABQAPRRwCUixhZbXupH1VqgASQlqPXIAFRp2ADUefgFQAG1YTEpFeHJsSQBzAF03JktWNhjQFQBuCkiGUJDwyLYw0Ex7ckwJGUQg2ojaNnwJSi5YhgLPdniEgAVxM2TKFFAwvMWpnKaWto6Rjyt2SWQcQKlZTB4AfiPpOVBFCUxcQ5UuCo0tHVB9Q2NTCHxqNi6oXWrXanWCoR67H6gzsklqikB5Fc1XI3XqiOePhAoFa6VA0AAFpg4PBSNBTHidPA9ERyHxftRbPF8IpIKNdrYAIzOAA0oDQrPZrFsACZnKVnKQqTTyAA6SRXOigbFiOliRACFmgCR6cBoHB8gXa3X67AqIA).